# PHP SoapClient __getLastRequest and __getLastRequestHeaders return NULL for successful call

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm going through tutorials on webservices and SOAP. In learning about these, I created a php file to act on the WSDL provided by w3schools that converts temperatures between Celsius and Fahrenheit.

I wrote the following PHP code which fires successfully:

```
$wsdl = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl);

// print_r ($soapClient->__getFunctions());
// print_r ($soapClient->__getTypes());

$parameters = array("Celsius" => "0");

$result = $soapClient->__soapCall("CelsiusToFahrenheit", array($parameters) );


echo "key: " . key($result) . "<br />" ;
echo "value: " . current($result) . "<br />" ;
```

The browser successfully returns the following:

```
key: CelsiusToFahrenheitResult
value: 32
```

I then tried to use the SoapClient methods `__getLastRequest()` and `__getLastRequestHeaders()` to take a look at the headers that were sent and see how they compare to what I had been reading and both method calls returned null

```
echo "Last call headers: <br />";
echo $soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders();
echo "<br />" ;
echo "Last call headers: <br />";
echo $soapClient->__getLastRequest();
```

I reviewed the notes and example in the [php manual for _getLastRequestHeaders()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequestheaders.php) and it looks like everything is set up correctly. I can't tell what I'm doing wrong :/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't set `trace` to true in the options argument of the constructor of the `SoapClient`, it won't store these. So simply put, this will work for you:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => true));
```

... which the manual page you linked to explicitly states:

> Note:
>
> This function only works if the SoapClient object was created with the trace option set to TRUE.